# Bluetooth cannot turnoff on Lenovo Ideapad 5 14ARE05

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, lenovo, thinkpad, realtek-wireless

Despite numerous forums on related matters I cannot find a fix that works. My bluetooth will not turn on, I think it is a driver problem but I really have a limited understanding of how this work.
Below some info on what is outputed in cmd line:

```
~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 5c:3a:45:2e:2c:dd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822ce driverversion=5.9.1-050901-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.62 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:83 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0500000-d050ffff
```

It seems to me that I need the rtw_8822ce but I cant find it when I run command like find /lib/modules

or

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
02:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c2)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
04:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
04:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
04:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
05:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
05:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
```

Thanks in advance to anyone with some time and patience to help me with this :)

Have a great day

Comment: To add some clarifications. When the problem is that when I  toggle bluetooth on it stays off.

Comment: So what do you want? To turn it on or off?

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? You have a mainline kernel that may require some other BT firmware than we have in Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi I would like to turn it on :)

Comment: Just did as sudo and it doesnt return anything

Comment: Yes sorry fogot to add that: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Comment: As for the kernel: uname-a returns: 5.9.1-050901-generic

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu kernel. You don't need `sudo`. Check is you copied the command correctly.

Comment: dmesg | grep -i blue
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: This is what it returns, sorry if the formating is bad its my first time here

Comment: it is weird. Boot with a normal Ubuntu kernel and try again.

Comment: Ok sorry but I have 2 questions regarding that: What is a normal ubuntu kernel and how do I boot on it ? I think initially I followed some tutorials to install this kernel because my wifi was not working.

Comment: You an use grub menu to select a kernel.

Comment: Thank you very much @Pilot6 bluetooth has returned. Wifi is working too. However now I can't adjust screen brightness. To be more precise I can change it with the controllers in  settings but it has no impact on the screen itself. Any idea ? Thanks again

Comment: And for the kernel I am now using: 5.4.0-52-generic

Comment: Ask a new question about brightness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the advice of @Pilot6 after changing to kernel 5.4.0 it started working fine again however I could not change my screen brightness anymore. I therefore chanded to kernel 5.7.0 where everything worked. Except now I my microphone is not recognized anymore...
But the initial issue is solved